# Why does top in the STL container adaptor stack return a const reference?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

The specification of the container adaptor `stack` says the `top` should return a `const` reference.  Why?

The same issue happens with `queue`'s `front` and `back`.  I can see in the case of `priority_queue` that modifiable access could mess with the priority and thus the "class invariant", but I know of no reason why you could not modify the `top` of a `stack` or `front`, `back` of a `queue`.

The most practical proxy for the specification is at cppreference.com:
[top](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top)

You can see it returns a `const_reference`, which is a `const` reference to the value held by the underlying container adapted.

Comment: It doesn't seem so https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top. You get a `const_reference` only in the `const` overload of `top`.

Comment: Can you show what specification you are looking at?

Comment: [`std::stack::top`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) has a non-`const` overload. You might be using a `const` container or `const` reference to a container and only seeing it's `const` members.

Comment: A practical example: [foo.top() = ...](https://godbolt.org/z/d47FJZ)

Comment: I made a mistake with this question, misread the cppreference page.  Now I can not delete it, the system would not let me.  What should I do?

Comment: Not much you can do.  You could try and convince the answerer that they should delete their answer so you can delete this.

Comment: @TheCppZoo what should you do ? not delete it. Questions and answers are not only for OP

Comment: @TheCppZoo The best alternative is to accept the answer. Not only because it's correct. it'll also get the question off the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does `top` in the STL container adaptor `stack` return a `const` reference?

Because that member function is const qualified and the container adaptor propagates constness.

There is a non-const-qualified overload that returns a mutable reference.

The reason why the const overload exists is so that you can access the top element of const stacks.

Quote from latest standard draft:

> [stack.defn]
>
> ```
> reference         top()             { return c.back(); }
> const_reference   top() const       { return c.back(); }
> ```